# Pythonic way to specify comparison operators?

Tags: jquery, python, django

(EDIT: I'm getting lots of answers about *implementation* (which I appreciate), but I am more concerned here with just the *specification syntax*.  Users of this plugin (i.e. Python/Django developers - not website users) will need to *specify* conditions, in a syntax that I am inventing.  So to rephrase the question...when writing a model or form class...which of the below syntaxes would *the archetypal Python/Django developer* prefer to specify the conditional display logic for form fields?)

I am looking for some advice for the most pythonic (readable, straightforward, etc) way to specify comparison operators for later use in comparisons (to be executed via javascript).  Something like (this is just one example that comes to mind - there are lots of other possible formats):

```
comparisons = (('a', '>', 'b'), ('b', '==', 'c'))
```

which would later be evaluated in Javascript.

The context is that I am working on a Django app (ultimately for distribution as a plugin) which will require users to write comparisons in whatever syntax I choose (hence the question about making it pythonic).  The comparisons will reference form fields, and will ultimately be converted to javascript conditional form display.  I suppose an example is in order:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    yes_or_no = models.SomeField...choices are yes or no...
    why = models.SomeField...text, but only relevant if yes_or_no == yes...
    elaborate_even_more = models.SomeField...more text, just here so we can have multiple conditions

    #here i am inventing some syntax...open to suggestions!!
    why.show_if = ('yes_or_no','==','yes')
    elaborate_even_more.show_if = (('yes_or_no','==','yes'),('why','is not','None'))

    #(EDIT - help me choose a syntax that is Pythonic and...Djangonic...and that makes your fingers happy to type!)
    #another alternative...
    conditions = {'why': ('yes_or_no','==','yes'), 
                  'elaborate_even_more': (('yes_or_no','==','yes'),('why','is not','None'))
                  }

    #or another alternative...
    """Showe the field whiche hath the name *why* only under that circumstance 
    in whiche the field whiche hath the name *yes_or_no* hath the value *yes*, 
    in strictest equality."""
    etc...
```

(hand waving...convert MyModel to ModelForm using model_form_factory()...gather all "field.show_if" conditions in a dictionary and attach to ModelForm as MyModelForm.conditions or something...)

Now in a chunk of javascript in a template, each condition in MyModelForm.condtions will become a function that listens for a change in the value of a field, and shows or hides another field in response.  Basically (in pseudo-Javascript/Jquery):

```
when yes_or_no changes...
    if (yes_or_no.value == 'yes'){
        $('#div that contains *why* field).show(); }
    else {
        $('#div that contains *why* field).hide(); }
```

The goal here is to let the end user specify the conditional display logic in a straightforward, pythonic way *inside the model definition* (there may be an option to specify the conditions on the form class instead, which I think is more "Djangonic"(??), but for my use case they need to go in the models).  Then my plugin behind the scenes turns that into Javascript in a template.  So you get conditional form display without having to write any Javascript.  Since this will be in the hands of python/django developers, I am looking for suggestions for the most native, comfortable way to specify those conditions.

Comment: If your question is asking how to design your API (as opposed to how to implement the API), perhaps you should head to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is designed to give you answers to how to implement things: API design is a bit more subjective, and would probably be better on the programmers stack exchange.

Comment: thanks mark, i was not aware of that distinction.  is there a way i can migrate it without duplicating, or should i just post a question there and link to this?

Comment: Well, to be honest, even there you might find that the question gets closed. It's pretty subjective: "How would you like to see this API designed?"

Comment: sure, it's subjective, as is what makes "good code" (or "pythonic code").  maybe it would be better phrased as "here is how i intend to design this API; does this align with norms and conventions such that it will be easily readable and easily written by those in the python/django community?"

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea:

```
import operator as op

a, b, c = 10, 7, 7

def f1():
    print 10

def f2():
    print 20

comparisons = ((a, op.gt, b, f1), (b, op.eq, c, f2))

for lhs, oper, rhs, f in comparisons:
    if oper(lhs, rhs):
        f()

=> 10
=> 20
```

With an appropriate representation you can dynamically specify comparison operators and their corresponding actions - implemented as functions. Take a look at the [operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module to see the available operators.

Comment: this is cool.  i will check into that module.  if i understand correctly though, the utility of that module is for *executing* the comparisons in python.  i'm actually just passing comparisons around in python, ultimately to be executed in javascript.  i edited the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about using django's syntax for querying?

```
>>> Entry.objects.filter(
...     headline__startswith='What'
... ).exclude(
...     pub_date__gte=datetime.date.today()
... ).filter(
...     pub_date__gte=datetime(2005, 1, 30)
... )
```

So it could be looks like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    yes_or_no = models.SomeField()
    why = models.SomeField(yes_or_no='yes')
    ... or ...
    why = models.SomeField(field__yes_or_no='yes')
    ... or even ...
    why = models.SomeField(field__yes_or_no__contains='ye')
```

Comment: I like the idea of using similar syntax to existing functionality.  Less mental overhead for users, less learning curve etc.  +1 for that.  I think for this to work I would have to provide custom subclasses of all the model fields (so that they know what to do with these new arguments I am inventing), right?

Comment: i am partial to using the existing forms.  i'm really just adding a carrier for some information that gets used later on down the line (by javascript), so i'm trying to keep it minimal.  but maybe it would make sense to create a new subclass, eg to also validate that none of the fields that are hidden at the time of submission contain any data...

Answer (score 1):

I really like how SQLAlchemy has handled this using operator overloading, so you might want to take a look at their implementation for some ideas.  For example, here is how it would do a query...

```
session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'fred')
```

As you can see, `User.name == 'fred'` actually creates a new object which can then be converted into a SQL string. This doesn't need to be a string, you can convert it into a JSON object if you want. Of course, this depends on having User.name support this sort of model, which I don't think that Django's models do.

But, you can do something similar, like this...

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop

    def __eq__(self, x):
        return "{0} == '{1}'".format(self.prop, x)

def test(x, fun):
    w = Wrapper(x)
    return fun(w)

class MyModel(object):
    yes_or_no = 'yes_or_no'

print test(MyModel.yes_or_no, lambda x: x == 'yes') # "yes_or_no == 'yes'"
```

The "Wrapper" object is the object that supports the actual operator overloading. In this example, we return a string, but you could return another Wrapper object to allow for compound statements (such as `(a == 2) & (b == 4)`). Exactly how you "wrap" the object is up to you. You could also wrap the model to make compound statements a bit easier...

```
model = f(MyModel)
print model.yes_or_no == 'yes' | model.yes_or_no == 'no'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a simple JavaScript expression generator. Rough sketch:

```
import json

class JSExpr(object):
    #base class
    def gen(self):
        """Generate the js for this expression."""
        raise NotImplementedError()

class CodeDump(JSExpr):
    def __init__(self, code_str):
        self.code_str = code_str
    def gen(self):
        return self.code_str

class PyLit(JSExpr):
    """Py literal to js literal, e.g. 4 --> 4, "hi" --> '"hi"' """
    def __init__(self, py_lit):
        self.py_lit = py_lit
    def gen(self):
        return "%s" % (json.dumps(self.py_lit),)

class If(JSExpr):
    """Generate an if statement from the given JSExprs."""
    def __init__(self, comp, if_true, if_false=None):
        self.comp = comp
        self.if_true = if_true
        self.if_false = if_false
    def gen(self):
        return "if (%s) { %s; } else { %s; }" % (
            self.comp.gen(), self.if_true.gen(),
            self.if_false.gen() if self.if_false else "")

class BinOp(JSExpr):
    """Helper for common binary operations ==, >=, etc."""
    op = None
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        if self.op is None:
            raise ValueError("Must sub-class and define '.op'")
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def gen(self):
        return "((%s) %s (%s))" % (self.left.gen(), self.op, self.right.gen())

class Eq(BinOp): 
    op = '=='

class StrictEq(BinOp):
    op = '==='

class Gt(BinOp):
    op = '>'

class And(BinOp):
    op = '&&'

class StrContains(JSExpr):
    """Non-bin op example"""
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def gen(self,):
        return "((%s).indexOf(%s) != -1)" % (self.left.gen(), self.right.gen())
```

Then all you have to do is somehow generate `JSExpr` instances from however the user inputs on the webpage, and generate an `If` out of it, using `PyLit` to insert values:

```
>>> print If(StrictEq(PyLit(4), PyLit([1, 2, 3])),
       CodeDump("console.log('weird things happening');")).gen()
if (((4) === ([1, 2, 3]))) { console.log('weird things happening');; } else { ; }

>>> print If(Gt(PyLit(4), PyLit(2)),
         CodeDump("alert('you did it!');"),
         CodeDump("alert('nope');")).gen()
if (((4) > (2))) { alert('you did it!');; } else { alert('nope');; }
```

Or you can use `CodeDump` to check variable names. The example from your question would be:

```
>>> print If(Eq(CodeDump("yes_or_no.value"), PyLit("yes")),
     CodeDump("$('#div that contains *why* field').show();"),
     CodeDump("$('#div that contains *why* field').hide();")).gen()
if (((yes_or_no.value) == ("yes"))) { $('#div that contains *why* field').show();; } else { $('#div that contains *why* field').hide();; }
```

The output is not pretty but it should work. And you can spend some time to make it nicer.

Answer (score 0):

This could be overkill, but you could use the Pyjaco tool to compile Python source into Javascript source.  Then you could write your comparisons in normal Python.  Hard to be more Pythonic than native Python!